# How to solve these two Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I have a homework assignment. I did all questions right but still unable to figure out this two queries so please help if you can. I appreciate you in advance.

I have FOUR tables:

```
EMPLOYEE which conatin the attributes (Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno)

Table DEPARTMENT have the columns ( Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date)

Table PROJECT have the columns ( Pname, Pnumber, Plocation, Dnum)

Table DEPENDENT (Essn, Dependent_name, Sex, Bdate, Relationship)
```

Q1. For the department that controls the most number of projects, list its name?
I came up with this query but still it just gives me each Department how many Projects it control but can not get it to work as giving me just the one that has the most :(

```
SELECT Dname, COUNT(distinct Pnumber) as NumberOfProjects
FROM Department, Project
WHERE Dnum = Dnumber
GROUP BY Dname;
```

Q2. Retrieve the names and Ssn of employee who have more dependents than any other employees?

I came up with this but idk why it does not work. I keep on getting an error

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Ssn
FROM Employee
WHERE max((SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Dependent
        WHERE Ssn = Essn));
```

BTW I am using MySql WorkBench 5.2 and The language is just SQL allowed to be used

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi thank you so much for editing :)

Comment: You tagged your question with three different DBMS systems. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For your first query, if you already have a list of all the departments with the number of projects they control, you have the work done. Add a little extra code to your query to finish the job.

If you ORDER BY the number of projects descending, the correct department will be the first in the list. And if you LIMIT 1, you will only SELECT that department.

---

Your second query needs more work, it does not provide the information you are looking for as cleanly as the first one. Do the same trick again, first get the information in order, then look for the top one. Your inner query should probably look something like this:

```
(SELECT Essn, COUNT(Dependent_name) AS Dependents
 FROM Dependent
 GROUP BY Essn
 ORDER BY Dependents DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for Q1:

```
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT Dname, COUNT(distinct Pnumber) as NumberOfProjects
    FROM Department, Project
    WHERE Dnum = Dnumber
    GROUP BY Dname
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct Pnumber) desc nulls last)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query for Q2:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Essn FROM(
    SELECT Essn,  Fname, Lname, COUNT(Dependent_name) as NumberOfDependents
    FROM Dependent, Employee
    WHERE Essn = Ssn
    GROUP BY Essn
ORDER BY NumberOfDependents desc)
LIMIT 1
```

This is inefficient if you run it using sub query like above because u r joining 2 large tables Dependent and Employee before extracting the employee with max. dependents. But it will work!

Comment: Subqueries are not inefficient, they are just like projection on query, you can check this by see execution plan on subqueries